# user field in a list definition thorough VS code (schema.xml)

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-definition

I create a user field in a list definition thorough VS code (schema.xml).

```
<Field ID="{0A9DDA0E-1EB8-467B-AFFA-AFB04057FCF7}"  Name="ChannelManager" DisplayName="Channel Manager" StaticName="MyUser" Type="User" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
 ShowField="Name"/>
```

When I view the field in list settings, Show field it set to Account rather than name and value is showing as i:0#.w|domain\account

Comment: Tried to set ShowField=”Name” and Presence=”TRUE” also. Not working.

Comment: Try with ShowField="Account"

Comment: Aanchal I need ShowField=”Name” not Account

Comment: You want domain\account or something else?

Comment: want domain\account

Comment: I don't think there is way to get this. You can also check from sharepoint UI, it's not showing domain\account for any option.

Comment: @Aanchal it does shows the name, check it again

Comment: Sivakumar any answer yet find ?

Comment: <Field ID="{F8A39C2E-E356-4518-911B-15097A585815}"  Name="Approver" DisplayName="Approver" StaticName="MyUser" Type="User" Required="TRUE"/>

Answer (score 1):

ShowField="ImnName" use this one to view user name

Comment: Hi Vidhya, welcome to community. While answering to questions in community you need to ensure that you provide details and explanation about your solution or approach. Detailing helps everyone, apart from person who had asked the query.