# web.EnsureUser() doesn't work for multi user and group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I update sharepoint list by code. In list I have people picker field. It allows multi userand  SharePoint group also.
Before allowing multi user and group it was allowed only single user. So I used below code amd it was worked fine.

```
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("ApproverField");
listItem["Approver"]=user;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
listItem.Update();
```

Now after changed to allow multi user and  SharePoint group this code doesn't work. Exception fires at web.EnsureUser(). So can anyone suggest to make the change?

Comment: Sivakumar does you find answer for question of your ???http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103880/user-field-in-a-list-definition-thorough-vs-code-schema-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the below function to store multiple users in People Picker

```
public SPFieldUserValueCollection GetSelectedUsers(PeopleEditor editor)
    {
        string selectedUsers = editor.CommaSeparatedAccounts;
        char[] splitter = { ',' };
        string[] splitPPData = selectedUsers.Split(splitter);
        SPFieldUserValueCollection values = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitPPData.Length; i++)
        {
            string loginName = splitPPData[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginName))
            {
                SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUsers[loginName];
                SPFieldUserValue fuv = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, user.ID, user.LoginName);
                fuv = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, user.ID, user.LoginName);
                values.Add(fuv);
                        }
                    }
                    return values;
    }
```

Comment: This will work for users. How to make this to work for group as well?

Comment: for groups the logic would be alltogether different with SelectionSet="SPGroup" in PeoplePicker control and the code would be different. Refer the link : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62606/how-to-retrieve-users-and-groups-seperately-from-a-person-or-group-column-via

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection values = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item["MultipleUsersField"];
values.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name));
item["MultipleUsersField"] = values;
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/multiple-user-insertion-in-sharepoint-list/

Comment: How to modify this code to work for group as well?